# Laravel- getting i think POST message after set_date submit

Tags: php, laravel, post, cookies, php-carbon

Hello i have a form which sets the date of voting start and stop, today I started to get this information on my screen. Could anyone tell me what does it mean ?[image]
This functionality uses 2 php files. 
MakeVoteController in which i take the date from form and then do Carbon::create and put them into database and there's function in my VotingStatus model. It is checking if the current date is in between begin and end date then it returns voting_status(started or stopped)
**VOTINGMGMT CONTROLLER**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class VotingMgmtController extends Controller
{
  public function start()
  {


    self::setStart();

    return view('panel.startvoting');
  }
  public function stop()
  {

    self::setStop();
    return view('panel.stopvoting');
  } //
  public function setDateView()
  {
        return view('panel.startvoting');
  }
  public function setDate(Request $request)
  {
    $rok_start = Input::get('rok');
    $miesiac_start = Input::get('miesiac');
    $dzien_start = Input::get('dzien');
    $godzina_start = Input::get('godzina');
    $minuta_start = Input::get('minuta');

    $rok_stop = Input::get('rok_end');
    $miesiac_stop = Input::get('miesiac_end');
    $dzien_stop = Input::get('dzien_end');
    $godzina_stop = Input::get('godzina_end');
    $minuta_stop = Input::get('minuta_end');

    $begin_date = Carbon::create($rok_start,$miesiac_start,$dzien_start,$godzina_start,$minuta_start,59,'Europe/Warsaw');
    $stop_date = Carbon::create($rok_stop,$miesiac_stop,$dzien_stop,$godzina_stop,$minuta_stop,59,'Europe/Warsaw');

    $now = Carbon::now('Europe/Warsaw');

    //Set begin and end date in database
    DB::table('voting_status')
      ->where('id',1)
      ->update(['voting_start_date' => $begin_date]);
    DB::table('voting_status')
      ->where('id',1)
      ->update(['voting_end_date' => $stop_date]);

    return redirect()->route('set_date')->with('success','Ustawiono datę rozpoczęcia i zakończenia głosowania');



  }
  public function setEndDate()
  {


  }

  private function setStart()
  {
    try
    {
      DB::table('voting_status')
        ->where('id',1)
        ->update(['status' => 'started']);
    }
    catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex)
    {
      return view('info.dash_service_unavailable');
    }

  }
  private function setStop()
  {
    try
    {
       DB::table('voting_status')
      ->where('id',1)
      ->update(['status' => 'stopped']);
    }
    catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex)
    {
      return view('info.dash_service_unavailable');
    }

    return true;



  }
  private function checkDate()
  {

  }


}
```

**VOTINGSTATUS MODEL**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use DB;
use PDO;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class VotingStatus extends Model
{
    protected $table = "voting_status";
    //check table VotingStatus whether started or not
    function checkStatus()
     {
        /*query database about status of voting and
        print output */
        DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $begin_date = DB::select('select voting_start_date from voting_status where id=1 ');
        $end_date = DB::select('select voting_end_date from voting_status where id=1');
        $now = Carbon::now('Europe/Warsaw');
        $begin_var;
        $end_var;
        foreach($begin_date as $key => $value)
        {
            $begin_var= (string)$value['voting_start_date'];

            echo $begin_var;

        }
        foreach($end_date as $key => $value)
        {
            $end_var= (string)$value['voting_end_date'];
            echo $end_var;

        }

        $carbon_start = Carbon::parse($begin_var,'Europe/Warsaw');
        $carbon_stop = Carbon::parse($end_var,'Europe/Warsaw');

        if(($now->gt($carbon_start)) && ($now->lt($carbon_stop)))
        {
            try
            {
                DB::table('voting_status')
                    ->where('id',1)
                    ->update(['status' => 'started']);
            }
            catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex)
            {
                dd("Upss start");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                DB::table('voting_status')
                    ->where('id',1)
                    ->update(['status' => 'stopped']);
            }
            catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex)
            {
                dd("Upss stop");
            }
        }

        DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);


    $db_stat = DB::table('voting_status')->where('id',1)->first();
        $status = $db_stat->status;

        return $status;


    }

}
```

**FORM**
[image]

Comment: you are returning the raw data of your request?

Comment: It's seems like yes, but i dunno why and how

Comment: You need more explanations, showing problem, attempts, error results, and expectation on your question so as to attract those who would like to answer this and so you can avoid your question downvoted. The expectation is not clear so make it clearer

Comment: It appears as though you have a dd() or die and dump. As @Omisakin mentioned, it appears to be the header of your POST data. This does not normally get spit out to the screen, so my guess is that you will find a dd({some variable in here}) somewhere in your code- probably at the beginning. Can you determine which file is causing this?

Comment: Ok, did little edit of my question

Answer (score 0):

Error has been fixed. After uploading newer version of application on the server there still was old version of web.php. In mentioned web.php my form submit was handled by function

```
set_date(Request $request)
{
 return $request;
}
```

Now everything works